# Unity Application switcher overlay is stuck and doubled

Tags: unity, application-switcher

About once every other day my Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop screen gets in a state where the Application Switcher overlay won't go away. This is the overlay in the middle of screen that appears when you press ALT+Tab. The mouse remains responsive but nothing I do will make the overlay go away. And then after pressing more keys, a second overlay (with a different order of app icons) appears over the first, and now neither will go away.

I'd like to know if I can fix this. But if I can't, then I'd like to know how I can restart the desktop window manager but keep my Tmux sessions intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Unity ever gets messy, I'd suggest just running:

```
unity --replace
```

It's not a fix but it should get things working again without interfering with existing windows.

Comment: 14.04: This kills the current session??

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Shouldn't. This should just reload the desktop manager. Everything running (save the DM) should stay running.